# Next JS prefetch return data

Tags: next.js, router, prefetch

Is there a way to return the json file that the prefetch method calls?

for example If I call

`router.prefetch('/myPage')`
NextJs makes a network request to `myPage.json`

The data I need is in that `myPage.json` file but the prefetch method doesn't have a return value.